# icCube Rest API (LoadMeasureGroup): load partitions error : internal error: mix add-rows w/ add-row

Tags: api, rest, iccube

I am using icCube Rest API to load a measure group of a schema. However, the loading breaks in the middle and sends to me this exception: load partitions error : internal error: mix add-rows w/ add-row.

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is an internal error that should never happens. Better to contact the icCube support to troubleshoot this issue.